# Boot Failure with Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

Tags: 12.10, boot, dual-boot

Okay I have a Futisu likebook AH512 that came with windows 8 64 bit installed. I want to have it dual boot with ubuntu 12.10 64 bit however I get 'setup Warning Boot Failure." With a continue button which goes back to boot menu selection.

I did have ubuntu before however I couldnt complete the installation due to problems it couldn't complete. I think this is what causing the boot errors however I don't know how I would completely wipe all traces of it from my HDD is thats the problem.

I have the same issue trying to boot fedora I had fedora before but then removed it when I installed windows 8 using my recovery disc.

Both version I have used a disc and USB to try and I get the same error.

Comment: Does Windows still boot? Have you tried going through the Ubuntu install process again?

Comment: Does any text come up (E.g. Failure Codes?)?

Comment: Yes windows still boots fine and the text is like I stated a white box with red outline saying 'Setup Warning' then in box below 'Boot Failure' and a continue button which takes me back to boot chooser. I've tried multiple times.